# jquery ui positioning keep changing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I developed a small tooltip plugin. it is working fine in IE,Chrome. In firefox it is working fine the first time. second time if I refresh the tooltip is oddly positioned..not sure what is happening.

here are the steps

1. in firefox first point your mouse over the 1st input box --tooltip will be near the input box

   1. then scroll down to second input box and mouse over the second input box - tooltip near the 2nd input box.
   2. click on the refresh button in firefox without scrolling up.
   3. now mouse over the first input box .. you will not see the tooltip..
   4. clear the history and come back you should see the tooltip near the input box.

   -->firefox 3.6.24/tryed updating to firefox 8 still the same problem

the code is in 
http://jsfiddle.net/HE8QN/

copy to desktop and try in your firefox...

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by refresh? If you could number your steps it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [jQueryUI - Position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

> Note: jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.

(And the result is that it somehow ignores the page's scroll offset)

You can sorta bypass it by making it an 'invisible block' by giving it the following CSS properties: `display: block` and `visibility: hidden` right before using the `position()` function and then removing them if nessesary.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/RmKyC/ I added a CSS class (`.hiddenTip`) that I added and then removed right before and after thecall to `tip.position({...})` (you could add the style as inline with `tip.css. ...` or whatever)

You have another problem also. You calculate the tooltip's position when the page loads. What happens when the items are rearranged? Maybe the text reflows because the window got resized or content is inserted or an element changes size. The tooltip is still shown in the old pre-calculated location. I think this is what @Eben Roux was talking about in his answer.

Click the H1 that says 'demo page' in my fiddle and you'll see how it gets a margin above it and everything moves down, except the tooltips.

EDIT: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frozenkoi/wKTnC/ bassed on @coool's modifications. Note that I added `!important` to `display` and `visibility` and some other small tweaks.

Comment: if I position as it enters then still there is the scroll problem. not sure what I am missing...(I guess the whole approach of using jquery ui  might not be the right one and I have to position by myself???)  http://jsfiddle.net/RmKyC/3/

Comment: @coool I made some small modifications to your fiddle in your comment above, see if it works a bit better. Added `!important` to the `visibility` and `display` properties to the class.

Comment: For me at least it made the tooltips jump a bit less around the page with the `!important`

Answer (score 2):

I have found that `position` acts strangely on elements that are not yet visible.  You might want to position your tooltip when it is being displayed.

Comment: I will end up positioning it every time the mouse move over..It is working fine in IE/Chrome..and even in ff only thing is when I refresh

Comment: Setting the position each time should be fine.  It is only setting it once on the mouse entering the element.

Comment: @EbenRoux: your last comment could be edited into your answer as an improvement.

Comment: @tzot: it could, but my answer hasn't changed --- nothing has improved :)

Comment: @EbenRoux: what do you mean by "setting it once on the mouse entering the element"

Comment: @coool: using the hover functionality the positioning should only occur on 'mouseenter' --- so the position isn't really set all that much.