# function in shown.bs.modal works only after second time calling of modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-modal

I'm having some problems with Bootstrap modal. The first time calling my modal, it's positioned about 20px to the left, but after that it's positioned correctly according to [`.position()`](https://jqueryui.com/position/)

Here's my code:

**HTML**:

```html
<div class="modal hide" id="AddCommentChat">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="my-element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal hide" id="MyModalWindow"></div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$('.my-element').click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  $('#MyModalWindow').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $(this).position({
      my: 'left top',
      at: 'right bottom',
      of: that
    });
    $('.modal-backdrop').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  }).modal();
});
```

**Update**:
The problem was solved by adding the next code:

```
        $('#ModalEditingDeleting').css({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
```

The final code is:

```
    $('.comment-manage').click(function(){
        $('#ModalEditingDeleting').css({
            left: 0,
            top: 0
        });
        var that = $(this);
        $('#ModalEditingDeleting').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
            $(this).position({
                my: 'left top',
                at: 'right top',
                of: that
            });
            $('.modal-backdrop').css('background-color', 'transparent');
        }).modal();
    });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you also include the markup?

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

The script currently shows a brief [Flash of Unstyled Content (FOUC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) because you're tapping into the **shown** event which, according to the [Bootstrap Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

> `show.bs.modal` is fired when the modal has been made visible to the user
>   (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

The only reason it *appears* to work after the first try, is because the `position()` function will leave the position as part of the markup

So this:

```html
<div class="modal" >
```

Will become this:

```html
<div class="modal" style="top: 34px; left: 104px;" >
```

And it will pick up where it left off and *then* attempt to reposition.  However, this is only good when the modal doesn't need to change between requests.

#### Solution - Part 1

Instead, of waiting until it's rendered, you need to tap into the **`show.bs.modal`** event which will fire before the element is shown and reposition at this time.

The rub, is that at this moment in time, the modal is hidden, and according to the documentation on [jQuery UI - Position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/):

> jQuery UI does not support positioning hidden elements.

#### Solution - Part 2

As a workaround, according to this [Stack Overflow question on jQuery ui positioning keep changing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324628/1366033), you can style the modal as an invisible block to help in calculating position:

```css
.modal {
   display: none,
   visibility: visible
}
```

#### Solution - Part 3

Additionally, there's no need to re-attach the `.on()` listener for every click of the button.  That initialization should happen in the beginning and then rely on the event handling to call the correct method.  This does introduce the additional problem that you can no longer pass the button into the event handler through the function scope.

So instead you need to add the calling button to the modal as a data parameter like this:

```js
$('#MyModalWindow').data("source", $(this))
```

So you can read it in the event handling like this:

```js
.position({
   my: 'left top',
   at: 'right bottom',
   of: $(this).data("source")
})
```

#### Here's a demo in Stack Snippets

```js
$('#MyModalWindow').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $(this)
  .css({
    'display': 'block',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
  })
  .position({
    my: 'left top',
    at: 'right bottom',
    of: $(this).data("source")
  })
  .css({
    'visibility': 'visible'
  });
})

$('.my-element').click(function(){
  $('#MyModalWindow')
    .data("source", $(this))
    .modal();
});
```

```css
.modal-backdrop.modal-backdrop {
  background-color: transparent
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-element" >
  Open modal
</button><br/><br/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-element">
  Open modal
</button>


<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="MyModalWindow" >
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal Content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
          Close
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```